# Loading glsl shaders in react/typescript with craco

Tags: reactjs, three.js, glsl, react-three-fiber, craco

I am trying to use GLSL files in my react/typescript project, but as far as I understand this requires modification to the webpack config. To do this I could eject my application or use a third-party library to modify the config. So in my case I am using a third-party library - craco, but I can't get is to work, here are my files:

craco.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.glsl$|\.frag$|\.vert$/i,
          use: ['webpack-glsl-loader'],
        },
      ],
    },
  },
};
```

my package.json:

```
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test"
  },
  ...
```

How am I importing the shaders:

```
import fragmentPars from './resources/shaders/fragmentPars.glsl';
import fragmentMain from './resources/shaders/fragmentMain.glsl';
```

decalration.d.ts:

```
declare module '*.glsl';
```

And here is the error I am getting:

> Program Info Log: Vertex shader is not compiled.
>
> VERTEX
>
> ERROR: 0:261: '/' : unexpected token after conditional expression
> ERROR: 0:554: '/' : unexpected token after conditional expression
>
> 256: #endif
> 257: #ifdef USE_DISPLACEMENTMAP
> 258:    uniform sampler2D displacementMap;
> 259:    uniform float displacementScale;
> 260:    uniform float displacementBias;
> 261: #endif/static/media/vertexPars.8e8f9976be7cf7583304.glsl
> 262: #if defined( USE_COLOR_ALPHA )

I have craco, craco types, webpack-glsl-loader dependencies installed. What could be causing this to not work?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this by changing craco.config.js to this:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    alias: {},
    plugins: [],
    mode: 'extends',
    configure: {
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            /* based on https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/#source-assets */
            test: /\.glsl$/,
            type: 'asset/source',
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
};
```